# Do we have logical reasons for diffetent durations of iddah?

Tags: quran, fiqh

In Quran the [Iddah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iddah) for divorced women varies from the Iddah of widowed women.

[Quran,2,228, divorced](https://quran.com/2/228)
[Quran,2,234, widowed](https://quran.com/2/234)

One might logically think that this period is to make sure the woman is not pregnant.

But why do they differ?

Comment: So you found the logic behind it. It is a matter of inheritance in the second case while in the first it is a matter of offspring and a possible reason for reconciliation.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, a matter of inheritance? I didn't understand what you mean.